# Bound on surface gradient in terms of gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a hypersurface and define the surface gradient of a function $u:S \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$\nabla_S u = \nabla u - (\nabla u \cdot N)N$$
where $N$ is the normal vector.

Is it possible to obtain a bound of the form
$$|\nabla u |_{L^2(S)} \leq C|\nabla_S u|_{L^2(S)}$$
where $C$ doesn't depend on $u$? Assume whatever smoothness of $N$ is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true by the following counter example. We note first of all that

$\nabla_{S}u = \nabla u - (\nabla u \cdot N)N$

is simply the tangiential component of $\nabla u$ on the surface. This is assuming that $N$ is unitary. To verify that this is the case we can check that that

$(\nabla_{s} u, N) = 0.$

Now consider that $\nabla u$ points in the direction of the unit normal. Then there will be no tangential component of $\nabla u$ on the surface $S$, i.e. $\nabla_{S} u = 0$. Then assuming $\nabla u \neq 0$ we have that

$| \nabla u|_{L^{2}(S)} > |\nabla_{S} u|_{L^{2}(S)} = 0.$